# Couldn't expand RemoteViews

Tags: android, exception, android-notifications

I try to create a custom notification but getting the following exception:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
android.app.RemoteServiceException: Bad notification posted from package com.my.app: Couldn't expand RemoteViews for: StatusBarNotification(pkg=com.my.app user=UserHandle{0} id=1 tag=null score=0: Notification(pri=0 contentView=com.my.app/0x7f03001b vibrate=null sound=null defaults=0x0 flags=0x2 kind=[null]))
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1423)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

My code looks like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyFragmentActivity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
PendingIntent launchIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);

RemoteViews notificationView = new RemoteViews(this.getPackageName(), R.layout.notification_layout);
notificationView.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.notification_icon, icon);
notificationView.setTextViewText(R.id.present_text, "Text Test");

Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(getApplicationContext());
builder
    .setContentTitle("Titel Test")
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_icon)
    .setContentIntent(launchIntent)
    .setOngoing(true)
    .setWhen(0)
    .setTicker("ticker Test")
    .setContent(notificationView);

NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, builder.getNotification());
```

The layout looks as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/notification_icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/present_text"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/notification_icon"
        android:gravity="center_vertical" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I'm running android 4.3. I've tried before with NotificationCompat and get the same error.

Does someone has an idea?

Comment: Please post `res/layout/notification_layout.xml`.

Comment: I've added the layout.

Comment: And don't forget do not put vectorDrawables to Notification, it is make the same exception.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You cannot put an `EditText` into a `RemoteViews`. `RemoteViews` is limited to a handful of possible widgets, specifically [those documented for use on an app widget](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html#CreatingLayout). And, for a `Notification`, I doubt that the `AdapterView` options, like `ListView`, will work either.

Comment: @CommonsWare it is also not alllowing me to use custom styling on textview is their any solution for this?

Comment: @NoumanCh: I do not recall trying that. If you cannot find an existing question more directly on this topic, ask a separate Stack Overflow question. Provide a [mcve], showing how you are attempting to use custom styling, and explain in greater detail what your results are.

Answer (score 7):

Not all views can be used in RemoteViews. A RemoteViews object can support the following layout classes:

‍`FrameLayout`

`LinearLayout`

`RelativeLayout`

`GridLayout`

`AnalogClock`

`Button`

`Chronometer`

`ImageButton`

`ImageView`

`ProgressBar`

`TextView`

`ViewFlipper`

`ListView`

`GridView`

`StackView`

`AdapterViewFlipper`

You can't use other layout classes like `EditText` or **CustomViews**.

Comment: how to change progress bar programmatically if we use our own progresssbar

Answer (score 3):

For me, it was because I was setting the text inside the remoteViews TextViews incorrectly. I was doing this:

```
remoteViews.setString(R.id.txt, "setText", "text");
```

Using one of these methods solved it for me:

```
remoteViews.setCharSequence(R.id.txt, "setText", "text");
//Or simply:
remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.txt, "text");
```

Comment: Using `setCharSequence` instead of `setTextViewText` worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I've found that using android:background="?attr/colorPrimaryDark" also causes a crash. 
When changed to android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark" it stopped crashing.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a ScrollView amongst your RemoteViews, remove it. This worked for me.